# Installing Mountain Lion on a fresh SSD

Tags: mac, ssd, osx-mountain-lion

I just bought a late 2012 Mac Mini and had the reseller change the hard drive to an SSD. Our deal was that she would change the drive but I will have to install the OS.

Question is… How do I go about it? Should I boot from the USB drive with Mountain Lion and do a clean install?

Also, I have an existing Mac Mini (late 2010), should I later do a Time Machine backup and then restore the back up to the new Mini?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I boot from the USB drive with Mountain Lion and do a clean install?

Yes.

If you haven't already, download the OS X Mountain Lion installer through the Mac App Store (e.g. from your old Mac). You can then use [Lion Disk Maker](http://blog.gete.net/lion-diskmaker-us/) to put the installer onto a flash drive of your choice.

Insert the USB drive and [boot from it](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948) by holding the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key during startup. Setup will commence, and you can install OS X Mountain Lion on the SSD.

Restoring an existing Time Machine backup is also possible, but first you'd need to boot the installer, which will then give you the possibility to recover from a Time Machine backup, if I recall correctly. A fresh installation would be preferred though. You can later migrate existing data through [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889).